# Rails Newbie: Collection Select & Controller Logic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, collection-select

I've read many related questions here, but I still don't understand how to do the following:
I have a "Country" model and I'd like to create a select form that will allow users to select any of the existing countries in the model, and be redirected to that country's "show" page.

My collection_select logic is:

```
<%= collection_select(:country, :country_id, Country.all, :id, :name, prompt: 'Select a Country') %>

<%= submit_tag "Find!", redirect_to (country.params[:id])%>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `country.params[:id]` what is it?

Comment: country.params[:id] is just the country_id.

Answer (score 0):

Rails uses MVC, so all logic should be in model(skinny controllers, fat models) and you should select your countries something like this `@country = Country.find(params[:country_name])`.
And then in view its gonna be `<%= submit_tag "Find!", redirect_to country_show_path(@country) %>`. If I understood your question right this is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Select form**

Create a drop down within your form:

```
<%= form_tag countries_path, method: :get do %>
    <%= collection_select(:country, :country_id, Country.all, :id, :name, prompt: 'Select a Country') %>
<%= submit_tag %>
```

In this case I am hitting `contries_path` and I have specified a GET request. The value selected by the form will be passed to `CountriesController#show`.

**Post to controller**

You can find the country, using the value passed to the form, via the params hash:

```
class CountriesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @country = Country.find(params[:country][:country_id])
  end
end
```

Comment: Tried this, but I'm getting an error - "undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass" - the error is on the controller line: @country = Country.find(params[:country][:country_id])

Comment: Is there anything in `params`? Try printing out `params` and see whether there is anything in there for `country` or `country_id`

Comment: Parameters:

{"id"=>"1"}

Comment: So is 1 the correct country_id? You can access it via `params[:id]`

Comment: 1 is the correct country_id. It is showing up now, but when I hit the submit button, the URL reloads but remains on the main 'index' page -     'http://localhost:3000/countries?utf8=%E2%9C%93&country%5Bcountry_id%5D=2&commit=Save+changes'

Comment: The action that the form posts to can be dictated by the url action specified at the top of the form, [See example here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#binding-a-form-to-an-object). Also, you probably don't want to do a `redirect_to` in the submit tag. The form should take care of this automatically, if set up correctly

Answer (score 0):

You will need both SelectCountryController (or whatever controller you're using to receive the selected country) and your regular CountriesController.

SelectCountryController:

```
class SelectCountryController < ApplicationController
  def index
    if params[:country_id].present?
      redirect_to country_path(params[:country_id])
    end
  end
end
```

Select country view (app/views/select_country/index.html.erb)

```
<%= form_tag "", method: :get do %>
  <%= collection_select(:country, :country_id, Country.all, :id, :name, prompt: 'Select a Country') %>
  <%= submit_tag "Find!" %>
<% end %>
```

Countries Controller:

```
class CountriesController < ApplicationController
    def show
      @country = Country.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

Don't forget to make sure you have the proper routes in your routes.rb file:

```
resources :countries
get :select_country, to: "select_country#index"
```

Comment: I tried this and it builds the select menu, but does not redirect to the (country_id) path.

Comment: If it is not redirecting, it must be that, somehow, params[:country_id] is not getting there.